# Set_post_thumbnail not working on Single Page, WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPress Codex states usage for 'set_post_thumbnail' is as followed:

```
<?php set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $thumbnail_id ); ?>
```

On the single-page.php I am working in, I have the following code snippets

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
// Returns the ID of the current post
```

And

```
$thumb_url2 = mpp_media_src( 'full' );
$thumb_url = $thumb_url2[0];
//Returns the full URL path of first MediaPress image.
```

& Lastly I have the following function in my functions.php file.

```
function get_attachment_id_from_src ($image_src) {
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE guid='$image_src'";
$id = $wpdb->get_var($query);
return $id;
}
```

Along with the following back on my single-page

```
$thumb_id = get_attachment_id_from_src($thumb_url);
```

---

A test of

```
echo $post_id;
```

returns

```
3544
```

which is the correct post id number.

A test of

```
echo $thumb_url;
```

returns the image url

```
http://localhost/mydomain/wp-content/uploads/mediapress/members/374/3535/ATOMS-FOR-PEACE2.jpg
```

which is the correct image url.

A test of

```
echo $thumb_id;
```

returns

```
1627
```

Which is the correct thumbnail id.

---

So why, I am wondering, after testing to make sure values in variables are proper and accurate, does inserting the following code seem to have no effect?

```
<?php set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $thumb_id ); ?>
```

Comment: That function returns an id on success, or false on failure. Set a variable equal to that function and do a var_dump on it to see what's returning.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting a `boolean false` returned...

Comment: After some testing, it seems the culprit lies with the thumbnail id. It is not sending correct id number.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue.

It seems that the function wasn't returning proper thumbnail id.

Turns out, MediaPress has something called

```
mpp_get_media_id
```

Which makes it very easy.

So I removed the function and just simply used this like so:

```
$mpp_media_id = mpp_get_media_id();
             $already_has_thumb = has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID );
             if ( !$already_has_thumb ) {
                 $setpt = set_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, $mpp_media_id );
                 $setpt;
             }
```